# Is the dilation of a convex body a subset of original convex body

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-geometry

Consider a convex body $\mathcal{C} \subset \mathbb{R}^p$, for some $p \in \mathbb{N}$.
That is $\mathcal{C}$ is a convex set in $\mathbb{R}^p$ with a non-empty interior.

For $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, define the $\lambda$*-dilation* of the convex body $\mathcal{C}$ as the set: 
$$\lambda \mathcal{C} := \{\lambda k \mid k \in \mathcal{C} \} $$

If we fix $\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$ such that $0 < \lambda_{1} \le \lambda_{2}$, 
then is $\lambda_{1} \mathcal{C} \subseteq \lambda_{2} \mathcal{C}$?
Or is there a simple counterexample? I expect this to be true since intuitively
the $\lambda$-dilation of the convex body $\mathcal{C}$ just re-scales the
convex body by a constant factor (or stays the same when $\lambda = 1$),
so that the subset should be preserved under the dilations described.
I was not quite able to relate the inequality relation between 
$\lambda_{1}, \lambda_{2}$ into the subset relation, when I tried
a "pick an arbitrary set element" type argument.

Could anyone help clarify the above?

Also does this then work under  general translation invariance 
and scaling i.e. consider a fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^p$, is the
following true?
$$y - \lambda_{1} \mathcal{C} \subseteq y - \lambda_{2} \mathcal{C}$$

In this case, one is "scaling, flipping, and translating the original"
convex body $\mathcal{C}$ using different scaling factors $0 < \lambda_{1} \le \lambda_{2}$ and translating by the same vector $y$.

**Edit:** Based on helpful comments by @DavidGStork, @TSF, and @JensSchwaiger, assume $0 \in \text{int}{\mathcal{C}}$, or if required that $\mathcal{C}$ has it's centroid at
the 0 vector.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a proof if the origin is in the convex body.

We can without loss of generality assume that $\lambda_2=1$. So, for some $0\leq\lambda\leq 1,$ we need $x\in \mathcal C\implies \lambda x \in\mathcal C$. This is certainly true, since $\lambda x$ is on the line segment connecting $0\in\mathcal C$ and $x\in\mathcal C$.

Comment: Thanks. Though I'm a little confused and would like to clarify. Comparing our notation, we have $\lambda_{2} = 1$, and $\lambda_{1} = \lambda$, right? If so, don't we want to show if $x \in \lambda \mathcal{C} \implies x \in \mathcal{C}$ i.e. it appears you are proving the inclusion the other way? (just comparing to my question asking whether $\lambda_{1} \mathcal{C} \subseteq \lambda_{2} \mathcal{C}$). Also why do you allow $\lambda = 0$. Appreciate any clarification.

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, you're right that I set $\lambda_2=1$ and $\lambda_1=\lambda$. Note that $$x\in\lambda\mathcal C\implies x\in\mathcal C$$ for all $x$ is equivalent to $$\lambda x\in\lambda\mathcal C\implies \lambda x\in\mathcal C,$$ since you're just replacing $x$ with $\lambda x$, and clearly $\lambda x\in\lambda\mathcal C$ if and only if $x\in\mathcal C$. The $\lambda=0$ thing isn't really interesting, it just happens to be true.

Comment: Thanks - that makes sense. For my final question on whether $y - \lambda_{1} \mathcal{C} \subseteq y - \lambda_{2} \mathcal{C}$, for a fixed $y \in \mathbb{R}^p$. I believe this is true since if $A \subseteq B \subset \mathbb{R}^p$, then $y - A \subseteq y - B$. Proof. $y - A := \{ y - a \mid a \in A \}$. Let $x \in y - A \implies x = y - a \text{ for some } a \in A  \implies x \in y - B$ since $a \in A \implies a \in B$ by the assumption $A \subseteq B$. Is this correct? And this works for any $A, B$ such that $A \subseteq B$ right? We just have special convex body case for $A, B$ here?

Comment: @user4687531 Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help and follow up!

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your definition, but it seems you're describing a general [homography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homography) (one of the Affine transformations).  If so, the below is a counterexample (assuming the "homothetic center" is at the point at the left).

[image]

Comment: It is a counterexample but they probably should add the condition that $0\in \mbox{int}\mathcal{C}$

Comment: Thank you, would the proposed argument work if $\mathcal{C}$ was centered at the origin i.e, centroid was shifted to the 0 vector in $\mathbb{R}^p$? Or under what sufficient condition on $\mathcal{C}$ would this argument hold true?

Comment: @TSF could you please show the proof when $0$ is in the interior of $\mathcal{C}$? I'm not sure how this is to be used in the proof. This counterexample is also useful to know, but I am more interested in the proof in the case where it holds true. I edited the question assumptions per your helpful comments.

Answer (score 0):

Counterexample in $\mathbb{R}$: $C=[1,2], \lambda_1=1, \lambda_2=2$. Then $\lambda_1C=C$ and $\lambda_2 C=[2,4]$. But the assertion is true for arbitrary $p$ when $0\in C$.

*Edit:* Assume that $0\in C$ and that $0<\lambda_1\leq\lambda_2$. Let $x\in \lambda_1 C$. Then there is some $\xi\in C$ such that $x=\lambda_1 \xi$.  Put $\mu:=\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_2}$. Then $0<\mu\leq 1$ and $\mu \xi=(1-\mu)0+\mu \xi\in C$ since $C$ is convex. This implies that $x=\lambda_1 \xi=\lambda_2\mu\xi\in \lambda_2 C$.

Comment: Thanks, could you please show the proof in the latter case, I've made edits to the question to confirm that $0 \in \text{int}{\mathcal{C}}$, sorry for not clarifying this.